# Does AWS support multiple VPN connections to one VPGW / VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn

In AWS we currently have one working VPN connection into our VPC subnet "prod".

We'd like to make another VPN connection to the same VPC subnet. Turns out one VPC subset can only have one Virtual Private Gateway (VPGW) associated to it. So we've tried to create the second VPN connection and let it share the same VPGW. The VPC subnets routing table now has 2 routes, one for each of the VPN remote side subnets, both with the same VPGW as target.

To be more concrete we have something like this:

- Two VPN connections (`VPN_A` and `VPN_B`) with remote side subnets CIDRs `192.168.161.0/24` and `10.100.1.0/24`
- One VPGW (`VPGW_A`)
- One VPC subnet (`SUBNET_A`) with CIDR `172.30.30.0/24`
- The instance we're testing from has both remote subnets (`192.168.161.0/24` and `10.100.1.0/24`) allowed in it's Security Group (SG) and I've also disabled the *Network source/dest checks* option.

`SUBNET_A` has the following routing table entries

```
Destination           Target
192.168.161.0/24      VPGW_A
10.100.1.0/24         VPGW_A
```

`VPN_A` is set up to use `VPGW_A`

`VPN_B` is set up to use `VPGW_A`

Presently `VPN_A` works as usual and the new `VPN_B` has tunnel state UP. However I'm not able to ping to a host inside `VPN_B`'s remote subnet.

The question is if 2 VPN connections to the same VPC/VPGW is something that should work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem isn't particularly clear.

You can only have one VGW per VPC, but you can have multiple VPN connections to the VGW/VPC. The [documentation here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/NetworkAdminGuide/Introduction.html) tells you what you can do. [This documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html) tells you how to set up a VPN connection.

> You can create up to ten VPN connections for your VPC. You can use
> multiple VPN connections to link your remote offices to the same VPC.
> For example, if you have offices in Los Angeles, Chicago, New York,
> and Miami, you can link each of these offices to your VPC. You can
> also use multiple VPN connections to establish redundant customer
> gateways from a single location.
>
> If you need more than ten VPN connections, complete the Request to
> Increase Amazon VPC Limits form to request an increased limit.

Comment: I'm sorry if the explanation was unclear. The documentation you've quoted vaguely says what I want should be possible. Upon further experimentation it turns out it does in fact work, so the above scenario with multiple VPN connections to one VPGW and one VPC is *VALID*. I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: Happy to have helped. Perhaps since the documentation is unclear you could either reply here or edit your question to help others who have this problem?